# Conditionally search in one sheet and copy the rows to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook called `Open Case Report.xlsm` with the sheets called `RAW_Data` and `Formatted`.

I want to create a macro that will search `RAW_Data` for a set of 2 names in column E and copy the entire row over to `Formatted` in a specific spot such as `A1`.

I have looked on here and found a few codes that are similar, but I can't seem to adapt the code to do what I want without getting a debug error.

Answer (score 1):

You can spot a value using the MATCH method. After that, you can use that **Rw** to transfer data to another sheet:

```
Sub FindRowTransferData()
Dim Rw As Long, myVAL As String

myVAL = Application.InputBox("Enter search value:", "Search", "John Doe", Type:=2)
If myVAL = "False" Then Exit Sub

On Error Resume Next
Rw = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(myVAL, Sheets("RAW_Data").Range("E:E"), 0)
On Error Goto 0
If Rw = 0 Then
    MsgBox "The search value '" & myVAL & "' was not found"
    Exit Sub
End If

'MsgBox "The search value '" & myVAL & "' was found on row: " & Rw

With Sheets("Formatted")
    .Range("B3").Value = Sheets("RAW_Data").Range("A" & Rw).Value   'name
    .Range("B4").Value = Sheets("RAW_Data").Range("B" & Rw).Value   'address
    .Range("C3").Value = Sheets("RAW_Data").Range("C" & Rw).Value   'phone
    'etc....
End With

End Sub
```

Based on the comments below, these suggested edits:

```
Rw = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(myVAL, Sheets("RAW_Data").Range("F:F"), 0)
On Error Goto 0
If Rw = 0 Then
    MsgBox "The search value '" & myVAL & "' was not found"
    Exit Sub
End If

'MsgBox "The search value '" & myVAL & "' was found on row: " & Rw

Sheets("RAW_Data").Rows(Rw).Copy Sheets("Formatted").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

Comment: This is close to what I was wanting, but I was needing something a little different.

The names are in the column F and that is the only thing I'm wanting to search for.

I am trying to find a way to auto-copy 2 names at a time from 1 sheet to another without any dialogues and get the entire row copied with the criteria in it.

Comment: Some suggested edits added above... ultimately you're going to have to be the one to figure out the exact syntax for what you need, I'm just trying to get you in the ballpark and spark your inspiration. ;)